# Using the PHP -W flag in a batch file

Tags: php, batch-file

I'm trying to remove all white space and code comments from my .php files by using the -W flag available from the PHP CLI. I'm using a batch file to recursively loop through each php file in my project. The batch command looks like:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /A-D /S *.php') DO "%php-exe-path%/php.exe" -w %%G > %%G
```

This just produces blank .php files (using the '>' redirector), however using the appending redirector ('>>') works fine.  I'm not sure if this is an issue with PHP locking the files or some problem with my batch command.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you'll do yourself a huge favor if you drop cmd.exe in favor of Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/) or at least MSYS (http://www.mingw.org/).  the POSIX shell is a much richer programming environment with way better documentation than cmd.exe, has much wider user community, and can be *much* more comfortable interactively.

Comment: just somebody: Regarding to the problem at hand this advice is pretty much bogus as the problem remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally: Don't ever pipe the output of a command that works with a file into the file again. Instead pipe to a temporary file, delete the old one and rename the temporary one to the old name. Kinda like the following:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /A-D /S *.php') DO (
    "%php-exe-path%/php.exe" -w %%G > %%G.temp
    del %%G
    ren %%G.temp %%G
)
```

Side note: Please don't use `for /f` over the output of `dir` as that can introduce some subtle but nasty errors. Instead use the proper way of iterating over files which is just plain `for`, and recursively with the `/r` switch:

```
FOR /R %%G IN (*.php) DO (
    "%php-exe-path%/php.exe" -w %%G > %%G.temp
    del %%G
    ren %%G.temp %%G
)
```

Comment: +1.  This is totally standard operating procedure when it comes to using the ">" redirection operator.

Comment: As this was returning the full path I needed to a change a couple of bits. Swapped the underscore with an appended '.temp' and changed the rename command to 'ren %%G.temp %%~NG.php'. Thanks for all the help.